# PTR (Reverse DNS) Imposible de configurar con IP dedicada

Tags: cpanel, dns

Holas, estoy teniendo un problema ya meses atras y ya a punto de rendirme queria preguntar aqui si alguien podria ayudarme por favor...

Resulta que tengo un dedicado, donde el servidor ya tiene un nombre de host s1.midominioprincipal.com, en este nombre de host que tiene la IP asignada compartida con para la mayor parte de las cuentas no tengo problema alguno.

El problema aparece cuando agrego una nueva IP, que seria asignada exclusivamente para una cuenta cpanel. Esto por cuestiones SEO y seguridad, no queremos compartir esta cuenta con la IP compartida por defecto.

Una vez agregada las propias DNS de esta cuenta nueva con la IP exclusiva (ns1.dominionuevo.com y ns2.dominionuevo.com) para que el sitio web use sus propias DNS y no las que tiene por defecto con el nombre de Host. al ver las RDNS en el Cpanel (Email Deliverity) me sale este siguiente aviso:

```
.............................
The system uses an alternate HELO of “s1.midominioprincipal.com” when sending mail from the “dominionuevo.com” domain.
.................................
The system sends “dominionuevo.com”s outgoing email from the “123.149.229.113” IP address. The only PTR value for this IP address must be “s1.midominioprincipal.com”. This is the name that this server sends with SMTP’s “HELO” command to send “logical.com.bo”’s outgoing email.

1 unexpected PTR value exists for this IP address:

dominionuevo.com
To fix this problem, contact your system administrator and request that they replace all PTR records for “123.149.229.113.in-addr.arpa” with the following record at ‘arin.authdns.ripe.net’, ‘r.arin.net’, ‘u.arin.net’, ‘x.arin.net’, ‘y.arin.net’ y ‘z.arin.net’:

Suggested “PTR” (PTR) Record PTR
................................
```

Para intentar solucionar el problema en Cpanel, el boton de reparar esta bloqueado.

Asi mismo si vemos en mxtoolbox.com, me sale lo siguiente: Reverse DNS is not a Valid Hostname

Por favor, si alguien podria ayudarme, perdon por escribir tanto rollo, pero intentaba hacerme entender.

Comment: Desde cPanel no puedes establecer un PTR, eso lo hace tu proveedor de IPs desde su panel de control, que entiendo que es tu proveedor de hosting (normalmente). Una vez tu IP tenga un PTR válido (para ello tambien deberas crear un registro A en tu cPanel con el nombre de PTR que vayas a ponerle apuntando a esa IP) entonces le puedes decir a cPanel que mande los correos de ese dominio con IP dedicada a través de esa IP y poniendo su PTR tambien en un archivo de configuración que hay en /etc/exim creo (ahora no recuerdo cual ni como).

Comment: Recomiendo que el PTR se llame algo asi como mail.dominionuevo.com o server.dominionuevo.com pero no solo dominionuevo.com, debe ser un subdominio o tendras otros problemas más adelante.

Comment: Hola masterguru, muchas gracias por responder, te comento...
El servidor es un servidor dedicado, por lo cual yo tengo acceso al WHM, desde donde se administra las IPs y las cuentas de Cpanel, desde aqui tu crees que pueda crear el PTR? aunque como dije, ya lo intente pero no pude. Asi mismo Ya he pedido que me ayuden a los de soporte, pero parece ser que ellos andan mas perdidos que yo, con lo cual sigo buscando la manera de hacerlo yo mismo.

Comment: Si desde WHM se podria crear este el PTR, como seria? segun te entiendo:

1.- Crear un registro A para un subdominio con el nombre de mail.dominionuevo.com (este seria el hostname que usaria)
2.- Desde Cpanel configurar que use esta configuracion del punto 1?

Saludos!

Comment: A ver si se explicarlo, un registro PTR no es más que una fila más dentro de una zona DNS, al igual que seria un fila con A, CNAME, etc... El problema no es cPanel o WHM, el problema es que la zona DNS de la IP normalmente va asignada a un servidor de nombres del proveedor de hosting, no al del cliente directamente, por lo tanto es el proveedor quien debe crear esa fila, porque el cliente no tiene acceso a esa zona DNS. En caso contrario si podrias crearlo, pero dudo que sea asi si dices que no saben ni lo que es un PTR tal cual.

Comment: Tu dile a tu proveedor que quieres crear una fila con un registro PTR (o bien una Reverse IP o una IP inversa o un Reverse DNS, que son otros nombres que tiene eso) que termine apuntando a mail.dominio.com, a ver si así te entienden. Mírate esto tambien para localizar el servidor de nombres de tu IP: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/dns/how-to-configure-reverse-dns-in-whm/ y darte cuenta de a quien debes pedirselo (o decirle a tu proveedor de hosting que lo pida). Lo normal es que en tu panel de cliente de tu proveedor de hosting aparezca un lugar para modificar eso entre tus ips.

Comment: Y aparte de lo que haga el proveedor de hosting, que debe hacerlo si te ha vendido esa IP, tu tambien debes crear un registro A en tu zona DNS apuntando a esa IP para que las verificaciones del PTR sean correctas después, sino, aunque ellos lo hagan por su parte, el PTR no estaria bien definido y seguirias teniendo problemas de verificación de PTR en los servidores de email donde pretendas enviar correos.